# AWS S3 Replication Fails Due to Bucket Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We've been using a template for bucket policies that worked well until we tried to enable replication. The first thing in the policy is a deny statement that has exceptions for a specific vpce, and three IP network ranges. The deny statement is followed by some allow statements. This worked well. When we tried to configure replication, we get replication failed status for any object added or updated. So we added the IAM role created for this replication to the deny exceptions and also to the allow statements as a principal. This still cause replication failure. We know the issue is the policy because removing the policy results in replication completing normally. Here's the format of the deny statement...

```
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1587152999999",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "<Bucket ARN>",
            "<Bucket ARN>/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "NotIpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "x.x.x.x/xx",
                    "x.x.x.x/xx",
                    "x.x.x.x/xx"
                ]
            },
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "aws:SourceVpce": "<VPCE ID>"
            },
            "ArnNotEquals": {
                "aws:SourceArn": "<IAM role created for replication>"
            }
        }
    },
```

Is the source arn of the IAM role used for replication the correct way to exclude it from the deny statement? Is there another approach to limit access while still allowing replication?

Answer (score 0):

Deny statements are always difficult. They often end up denying more than expected.

I think the above statement is saying:

- Access to this S3 bucket is denied if:

  - You aren't coming from one of these IP addresses, *AND*
  - You aren't coming through that VPC Endpoint, *AND*
  - You aren't using that IAM Role

This should effectively be saying "Don't deny if any of the above are True" (that is, they are using one of the IPs, OR the VPC Endpoint OR the IAM Role).

See: [Creating a condition with multiple keys or values - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_multi-value-conditions.html)

This means that your statement *should* be correct, but you report having problems. I can't see an immediate problem with what you are doing, but try starting by *only* having the IAM Role condition, test whether it is working correctly, then add the other conditions one-at-a-time to identify the cause of the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with my policy was in the Role ARN.

I used "aws:SourceArn" but should have used " "aws:PrincipalArn"

I'm pretty sure I got SourceArn from the policy generator. I ended up opening a case and after a few iterations with support I got the "aws:PrincipalArn". That worked!